# How to validate any contact details field

Tags: database, validation, jsp

How can I validate contact details field in database for accepting mobile number, fax or landline number in jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try HTML5 pattern:

```html
<input type="number" pattern=".{9}" title="Enter Valid Phone No" required>
```

Edit the regex in the code above to suit the kind of phone number you expect, you can also use regex in your backend code.

Comment: Sir I didn't get 'regex'??plz explain

Comment: @Siddhartha Regex stands for Regular Expression. In the code I pasted, it's the `.{9}`. You can search for Regex+phone numbers online to learn more.